# Get unique and duplicate values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, for-loop, filter

I have this JSON data:

```
vm.userListData = [{
        "listId": 1,
        "permission": "READ"
    }, {
        "listId": 2,
        "permission": "WRITE"
    }, {
        "listId": 2,
        "permission": "READ"
    }, {
        "listId": 3,
        "permission": "READ"
    }, {
        "listId": 3,
        "permission": "WRITE"
    }, {
        "listId": 4,
        "permission": "WRITE"
    }, {
        "listId": 5,
        "permission": "WRITE"
    }]
```

And this one:

```
vm.userComplementaryList = [{
    "listId": 1,
    "confidentiality": "PUBLIC",
    "listName": "List name here..1",
    "permission": "WRITE"
}, {
    "listId": 2,
    "confidentiality": "PUBLIC",
    "listName": "List name here..2",
    "permission": "READ"
}, {
    "listId": 3,
    "confidentiality": "CONFIDENTIAL",
    "listName": "List name here..3",
    "permission": "WRITE"
}, {
    "listId": 4,
    "confidentiality": "CONFIDENTIAL",
    "listName": "List name here..4",
    "permission": "WRITE"
}, {
    "listId": 5,
    "confidentiality": "CONFIDENTIAL",
    "listName": "List name here..5",
    "permission": "READ"
}]
```

With this two JSON data I must filter and get unique values and push them into array and values which are duplicated(listId and permission), push them into other array.
I done this:

```
vm.listForGrid = [];
vm.listForDropDown = [];

(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < vm.userComplementaryList.length; i++) { 
        for(var j = 0; j < vm.userListData.length; j++) {   
            if( (vm.userComplementaryList[i].listId == vm.userListData[j].listId) && (vm.userComplementaryList[i].permission == vm.userListData[j].permission) ) {
                vm.listForGrid.push(vm.userComplementaryList[i]);
            }
            else {
                vm.listForDropDown.push(vm.userComplementaryList[i]);
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

The `vm.listForGrid` are ok but the `vm.listForDropDown` values are more then once same value, I must `break` loop.

**The duplicated values are same values with listId and permission in both arrays**

Thank you!

Comment: `break` when you found listid same.

Comment: put your code on plunkr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a sorter version using array.some

```
vm.userComplementaryList.forEach(function(vCom) {
    vm.userListData.some(function(vUser) {
        return (vCom.listId == vUser.listId && vCom.permission == vUser.permission);
    }) ? vm.listForGrid.push(vCom) : vm.listForDropDown.push(vCom);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use still a hash table as reference if the permission is given. Then you need just a single loop without nested loop to sort the items.

```js
var vm = {},
    permissions = {};

vm.userListData = [{ "listId": 1, "permission": "READ" }, { "listId": 2, "permission": "WRITE" }, { "listId": 2, "permission": "READ" }, { "listId": 3, "permission": "READ" }, { "listId": 3, "permission": "WRITE" }, { "listId": 4, "permission": "WRITE" }, { "listId": 5, "permission": "WRITE" }];
vm.userComplementaryList = [{ "listId": 1, "confidentiality": "PUBLIC", "listName": "List name here..1", "permission": "WRITE" }, { "listId": 2, "confidentiality": "PUBLIC", "listName": "List name here..2", "permission": "READ" }, { "listId": 3, "confidentiality": "CONFIDENTIAL", "listName": "List name here..3", "permission": "WRITE" }, { "listId": 4, "confidentiality": "CONFIDENTIAL", "listName": "List name here..4", "permission": "WRITE" }, { "listId": 5, "confidentiality": "CONFIDENTIAL", "listName": "List name here..5", "permission": "READ" }];

vm.listForDropDown = [];

vm.userListData.forEach(function (p) {
    permissions[p.listId] = permissions[p.listId] || {};
    permissions[p.listId][p.permission] = true;
});

vm.listForGrid = vm.userComplementaryList.filter(function (a) {
    if (permissions[a.listId] && permissions[a.listId][a.permission]) {
        return true;
    }
    vm.listForDropDown.push(a);
});

console.log(vm.listForGrid);
console.log(vm.listForDropDown);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this:

```
(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < vm.userComplementaryList.length; i++) { 
        var found = false;
        for(var j = 0; j < vm.userListData.length; j++) {   
            if( (vm.userComplementaryList[i].listId == vm.userListData[j].listId) && (vm.userComplementaryList[i].permission == vm.userListData[j].permission) ) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(found) {
            vm.listForGrid.push(vm.userComplementaryList[i]);
        }
        else {
            vm.listForDropDown.push(vm.userComplementaryList[i]);
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: you still need a nested loop for finding the same element.